# curl to vertexAI private endpoint doesn't work (wrong url)

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I managed to deploy a custom model on a private endpoint on vertexAI.

I want to make predictions using that endpoint. I try to follow the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/using-private-endpoints#sending-prediction-to-private-endpoint). So I created a compute engine in the same network in which the private endpoint is deployed.
Then I'm trying to use curl to make a request: curl -X POST -d@PATH_TO_JSON_FILE  http://ENDPOINT_ID.aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/models/DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID:predict
But the URL seems somehow wrong:

```
curl -X POST -d data_281537.json http://1413646497878114304.aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/models/2155333061510692864:predict

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/models/2155333061510692864:predict</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I'm pretty sured I'm doing something wrong but I can't get my hand on it... Maybe someone would know?

Also from the google vertex AI admin page, in the "online prediction" tab, when I go to my private endpoint, there's a clickable button "prediction" (and also "health") that leads to the same URL I used in my curl request and that also leads to a 404.

Comment: Do you have route to /healthz ? Otherwise it would kill the container after 10 seconds.

**Purpose:**
The health check route will accept a GET request. This request won’t have any special information but will expect a response from the server informing it as to whether it is ready to take predictions or not. Basic checks are the following:

 - assume deserialization check
 - returns something with code 200

```
@app.get("/healthz")
async def health_check():
    return JSONResponse(content={"status": "healthy"}, status_code=200)
```